# Espressif tool chain broken after macOS Monterey 12.3 beta 3 install

Tags: macos-monterey, platformio

After Monterey 12.3 beta 2 installed, the Espressif tool chain is broken. If you compile with platformIO you'll get the following error:

```
               ^
Linking .pio/build/esp32dev/firmware.elf
/Users/stephanedeluca/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/5.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld: /Users/stephanedeluca/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa32/bin/../libexec/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/5.2.0/liblto_plugin.so: error loading plugin: dlopen(/Users/stephanedeluca/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa32/bin/../libexec/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/5.2.0/liblto_plugin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: /opt/osxcross/target/bin/../x86_64-apple-darwin12/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/stephanedeluca/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa32/libexec/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/5.2.0/liblto_plugin.0.so
  Reason: tried: '/opt/osxcross/target/bin/../x86_64-apple-darwin12/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib' (no such file)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio/build/esp32dev/firmware.elf] Error 1
```

Looking at my Mac, there is no /opt/osxcross.

I have searched on another Mac with the beta 1 where the tool chain was still working the presence of the folder, and guess what?! there's none!

Any idea what as actually broken by the beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, here is a work around: we are going to provide the missing `/opt/osxcross` folder and contents.

1. *If you do not have gcc installed* (this should be unlikely though, install `gcc` to get the folder content, as follows:
   `$ brew install gcc`
2. *Create the missing `/opt/osxcross` folder* as follows:
   `$ sudo mkdir -p /opt/osxcross/target/bin/../x86_64-apple-darwin12/lib/`
   Note that you'll be prompted for your password.
3. And, finally, copy the folder contents from the gcc build as follows:
   `$ sudo cp /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/lib/gcc/11/libstdc++.6.dylib /opt/osxcross/target/x86_64-apple-darwin12/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib`

This completes the fix.

You must restart `vscode`, `Arduino IDE` or whatever tool you use. And then build your project, which should compile successfully.

And voila.

Comment: in my case the path is different for the third command, 
`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/lib/gcc/11/libstdc++.6.dylib` is where the library resides.